# Iterate over a tuple of lists

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I have a tuple of lists. Each list in the tuple has the same number of elements. How can I iterate over it in a for loop

Ex:

```
tupleList = ([1,2,3], ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
for (val, label) in <something>:
    print val, label
```

Should output:

```
1, label1
2, label2
3, label3
```

NOTE: This list of tuples could contain more than two lists.

PS: For those who have opted this as a duplicate, please check the responses for the correct solution. It's different from iterating through two separate lists.

Comment: Can your `tupleList` contain more than 2 lists?

Comment: Yes, more than 2 lists is possible. But the number of lists present, I would know in advance.

Comment: You can apply a loop like this - `for i in range(1, len(tupleList), 2)`. Inside that you can apply `zip` on `tupleList[i]` and `tupleList[i+1]` like mentioned in the answers.

Comment: as you may note, zipping each individual element of the tuple separately is the longer solution. Whereas @Roelant's solution offers a shorter alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use zip and flatten the tuple_list with the asterix syntax.

```
tuple_list = ([1,2,3], ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
for val, label in zip(*tuple_list):
     print(val, label)
```

If you're still in python 2.7:

```
import itertools
tuple_list = ([1,2,3], ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
for val, label in itertools.izip(*tuple_list):
     print val, label
```

Comment: You may also want to try `itertools.izip` to create an iterator instead of a list in Python 2

Comment: Thanks, added it :)

Comment: @hlt No need of `itertools.izip` it will work with `zip` in Python2

Comment: @RahulKP: generators are more beautiful than lists ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using zip

```
tupleList = ([1,2,3], ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
for (val, label) in zip(tupleList[0],tupleList[1]):
    print(val, label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In [3]: for v,k in zip(*tupleList):
   ...:     print v,k
   ...:     
1 label1
2 label2
3 label3
```